# Зависимые слова, причастия и -н-/-нн-

Tags: сказуемые, удвоенные-буквы, причастный-оборот, спп

Возник спор относительно зависимых слов при составных именных сказуемых и частей сложноподчинённых предложений, в которых употреблены причастия/отглагольные прилагательные. Из-за этого не совсем ясно, от каких именно слов зависят обстоятельства, и соответственно, сколько -Н- писать в причастии/отглагольном прилагательном.

Несколько примеров:

1. *"Минское «Динамо» будет сеян(н)ым в первых трех раундах квалификации Лиги Европы"* - обстоятельство *"в раундах"* зависит от сказуемого *"будет сеян(н)ым"*, но от какого слова конкретно, и сколько -Н- в этом случае должно быть в слове *"сеян(н)ый"*?
2. *"Минское «Динамо» и солигорский «Шахтер» начнут свой путь с первого квалификационного раунда, где попадут в список сеян(н)ых"* - можно ли считать, что слово *"где"* зависит от слова *"сеян(н)ых"*? Отличается ли этот пример чем-то от первого?
3. *"Во втором квалификационном раунде подопечные Гуренко и Кубарева также окажутся в числе сеян(н)ых."* - отличается ли этот пример от первого благодаря появлению слов *"в числе"* и замене глагола?

Answer (score 3):

**Сеяный** – это спортивный термин, он пишется всегда одинаково. Сеяный игрок или команда имеют привилегии при определении турнирной сетки и не участвуют в жеребьёвке.

**Минское «Динамо» будет сеяным** – при отсутствии определяемого существительного (сеяная команда) термин "сеяный" приобретает  предметное значение.

Пример: Сеяный игрок в теннисе.
[Кто такой «сеяный игрок» в большом теннисе?](http://alvin-almazov.ru/tennis-rus/seyanyj-igrok/)

**Признаки прилагательного:** слово имеет **переносное** (не прямое) значение, обозначает **качественный признак**. "Сеяная команда" – команда высокого класса, получившая в турнире  особый статус: она не участвует в жеребьевке, а получает место в турнирной таблице заранее.

Comment: Sibylla, таким же образом, я вам могу привести уйму других ссылок, где "сеянный" пишется с двумя нн. ***Минское «Динамо», а также «Шахтер» в случае прохождения 1-го квалификационного раунда Лиги Европы будут сеянными при жеребьевке 2-го*** квалификационного раунда.

Comment: Серж, да примеров-то  много, вот только как доказать, что это грамотно написанные примеры. Слово сложное для орфографии, поэтому правило применяют чисто формально. Как мне кажется, надо исходить из того, что  термин должен иметь постоянную форму написания (в данном случае форму прилагательного с одним Н).  Можно было бы его вообще заключать в кавычки, если оно используется не в  текстах на спортивную тему.

Comment: – Sibylla, вы абсолютно правы, говоря, что что слово для орфографии сложное. В этом значении оно не зафиксировано словарями, термин не устоявшийся, отсюда разнобой в правописании. Лучше, как вы сказали, "писать в кавычках" ***(кстати, такой вариант тоже есть в сети)*** .  Пока же, надо при менять формальное правило. До тех пор, пока термин не устоится.

Comment: @Серж, вообще говоря, этот спор и возник на одной из спортивных площадок, где всегда писали "сеянными", откуда Вы и можете почерпнуть цитаты за последние пару лет, так что цитаты из новостей малозначимы за неимением возможности верить их априорной грамотности.

А что является показателем "устоявшегося термина"? Его появление в толковых словарях?

Comment: @Viachaslau Kachurka, да, это словарная фиксация. А в этом значении он не зафиксирован пока. Поэтому все же лучше применять правило. См. ответ Екатерины Каштановой.

Answer (score 2):

1.***Минское «Динамо» будет сеянным в первых трех раундах квалификации Лиги Европы***. - Обстоятельство "в раундах" зависит от  "сеянным". Пишем НН, это причастие с зависимым словом.

2.***Минское «Динамо» и солигорский «Шахтер» начнут свой путь с первого квалификационного раунда, где попадут в список сеяных.*** - Пишем в прилагательном Н, так как нет зависимого слова, приставки, образовано от глагола несов. вида. Прилагательное здесь, кстати, переходит уже в существительное. Обстоятельства ГДЕ и В СПИСОК зависят от ПОПАДУТ.

3.***Во втором квалификационном раунде подопечные Гуренко и Кубарева также окажутся в числе сеяных.***- Пишем Н, так как нет зависимых слов, нет приставки, несов.вид. Это предложение отличается от первого: в одном случае мы имеем дело с причастием,входящим в состав сказуемого,  а в другом (и в третьем тоже) - с субстантивированным прилагательным, являющимся в предложении несогласованным определением: *в списке(каком?) - сеяных, в числе (каком?) - сеяных.*

Comment: Список сеяных, про спортивную команду?? Ужас. С другой стороны, конечно, лучше список сеяных чем список саженых.

Comment: А по какому признаку можно определить и объяснить, что в первом случае именно причастие, а не прилагательное?

Исходя из контекста ситуации, это ведь не совсем "Морковь будет сеянной в полях весной", где очевидно действие, а о приобретении статуса "сеяная команда", аналогично теннисному жаргону "сеяного игрока".

Comment: @ Viachaslau Kachurka,как объяснила Екатерина, в первом примере при причастии имеются зависимые слова. А это уже признак причастия. Во-вторых, даже если в первом примере не было бы зависимых слов, "сеянным" все равно было бы причастием. Поскольку в предложении есть глагол будет, который указывает временной признак.

Comment: Ср.: ***Будучи раненным, командир еще отдавал приказания*** ( **слово будучи вносит временное значение в форму раненным, усиливая тем самым ее глагольность**). - На опушке показались солдаты, выносившие убитых и раненых товарищей (признак обозначен прилагательным).

Comment: >> *Список сеяных, про спортивную команду??* – да, это термин. Сильнейших рассеивают, чтобы они не играли между собой на ранних стадиях турнира с выбыванием.

Comment: @ViachaslauKachurka, "сеяный" нигде не причастие. Оно потеряло связь с глаголом "сеять", это просто термин. Никак нельзя сравнивать с раненным и с "сеянной весной морковкой" (фраза сама по себе жуть, так не говорят, нужна приставка).

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что это слово утратило связь с глаголом?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал, что во всех случаях надо писать с одним Н. Действия тут нигде нет, а потому это отглагольные прилагательные, а не причастия. "Сеяный" – это признак, это означает "входящий в число сильнейших". Вот если бы с приставкой, тогда да, тогда пришлось бы писать с НН.