# О "посеянных" теннисистах

Tags: лексика, заимствования

1. Прочитала новости в обычной прессе: ***Несеяная** теннисистка выиграла Уимблдон впервые в истории.*

***Несеяная*** даже без кавычек. Прочитала [информацию о "посеве"](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2253176-posejannyj-tennisist-kto-ego-posejal-i-pochemu.html)

Все понятно: термин "***посеянные игроки***" соответствует английскому "***seeded players***". Понимаю, что изменить ничего нельзя: терминология!

2. **А все-таки по-русски никак нельзя было сказать?**

Что вы думаете **о правильности** такого заимствования? Нужно ли использовать **кавычки** при записи?

К какому **стилю речи** относится этот термин? В общеупотребительных словарях его нет, это **специальная** лексика? А в каких **словарях** фиксируются подобные слова?

Спасибо.

Вопрос обсуждался раньше  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432294/Зависимые-слова-причастия-и-н-нн/432321#432321](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432294/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%BD/432321#432321)

Comment: А все-таки «по-русски» никак нельзя было сказать? /// Тут кавычки будут нелишние: ведь слово-то (*посев*) нашенское всё же.

Comment: В словаре общеупотребительной лексики есть отсев абитуриентов, но посева нет. Посев - спортивный термин. Посе́в (се́яние) — назначение участникам или командам, принимающим участие спортивном турнире, номера в предварительном рейтинге в рамках жеребьёвки.  Но посеянный игрок - это уже слишком даже для спорта. Сленг какой-то.